# Map Model with Collection Inside

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have an API endpoint something like this:

```
        [HttpGet("{shoppingCartId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetShoppingCart(int shoppingCartId)
        {
            var shoppingCart = await context.ShoppingCarts.Include(c => c.ShoppingCartItems).SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == shoppingCartId);

            if (shoppingCart == null)
                return NotFound("There is no shoppingCart for specified query.");

            return Ok(shoppingCart);
        }
```

It works fine. Returns a ShoppingCart with ShoppingCartItems as expected.

But, I dont want to return shoppingCart but shoppingCartResource.
Something like that:

```
        [HttpGet("{shoppingCartId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetShoppingCart(int shoppingCartId)
        {
            var shoppingCart = await context.ShoppingCarts.Include(c => c.ShoppingCartItems).SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == shoppingCartId);

        if (shoppingCart == null)
            return NotFound("There is no shoppingCart for specified query.");

        var shoppingCartResource = mapper.Map<ShoppingCart, ShoppingCartResource>(shoppingCart);
        return Ok(shoppingCartResource);
    }
```

As you can see the ShoppingCart model has a Collection of ShoppingCartItem inside.

```
    public class ShoppingCart
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ShoppingCartItem> ShoppingCartItems { get; set; }

        public ShoppingCart()
        {
            ShoppingCartItems = new Collection<ShoppingCartItem>();
        }
    }
```

And here is the ShoppingCartResource model

```
  public class ShoppingCartResource
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ShoppingCartItemResource> ShoppingCartItemResources { get; set; }

        public ShoppingCartResource()
        {
            ShoppingCartItemResources = new Collection<ShoppingCartItemResource>();
        }
    }
```

Mapping Code is:

```
 CreateMap<ShoppingCart, ShoppingCartResource>();
 CreateMap<ShoppingCartItem, ShoppingCartItemResource>();
```

There is no error but I got the only shoppingCartResource with empty ShoppingCartItemResource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are lacking single line telling AutoMapper where from it should map `ShoppingCartItemResources` because corresponding property in source object does not have the same name - `ShoppingCartItems`, thus it won't work automatically. Just add this:

```cs
CreateMap<ShoppingCart, ShoppingCartResource>()
    .ForMember(
        dst => dst.ShoppingCartItemResources, 
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.ShoppingCartItems));
CreateMap<ShoppingCartItem, ShoppingCartItemResource>();
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, AutoMapper follows a naming convention that automatically creates a map between a source property and a target property if their names match, and you don't have to configure anything for this.
But, if you want a map between two properties and their names don't match, then you have to explicitly define a configuration for that map.

Your `ShoppingCartResource` and `ShoppingCart` objects both have properties named `Id` and `DateCreated`, and so they got mapped automatically.

To get a map between your `ICollection` properties -

1. if you want an automatic map, you have to give them a matching name
2. if you want to keep distinction in naming, you have to explicitly define a configuration for their mapping. Something like -

```cs
CreateMap<ShoppingCart, ShoppingCartResource>()
    .ForMember(d => d.ShoppingCartItemResources, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.ShoppingCartItems));

CreateMap<ShoppingCartItem, ShoppingCartItemResource>();
```